# Regex to extract characters within json

Tags: python, regex

What would be the best regex to extract the following:

```
s = '":"1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A="'
==> 14349198.17660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0.juKeQmbW8A=
```

It is a string between either a `'` or `"` with length > 5 and that is terminated by `'` or `"`. The best I could get was:

```
>>> re.search(r'''[\'|\"](.+)[\'+\"]''', x).group(1)
':"1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A='
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to replace use str.translate:

```
s = '":"1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A="'

if len(s) > 5:
    print(s.translate(None,""":"'"""))
1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A=
```

For python3 you need to create a mapping using the ord of the characters you want to replace:

```
s = '":"1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A="'

print(s.translate({ord('"'):"",ord("'"):"",ord(":"):""}))
```

If you have json you could also extract by key, if it were json though you would not have any `'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> re.sub(r'[":]', '', s)
'1434919817660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0juKeQmbW8A='
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try doing an string `replace` here:

```
s.replace('"','').replace(':','').replace("'",'').strip()
14349198.17660.wFzJl5KnFq1tyg5X0.juKeQmbW8A=
```